# Stored Procedure Error: Ambiguous column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Getting the follow error for each column (note, both tables have the same column names, but I am not sure how to prefix the table data type)

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertNonExistingNode, Line 21
>   Ambiguous column name 'NodeTypeId'.

```
USE NWatchEntitiesUnitTest
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNonExistingNode (@TableVariable dbo.NodeTableType READONLY, 
                                        @ScalarParameter nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO NWatchNodes WITH (ROWLOCK) (
      NodeTypeId,
      Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Name,
      Alias) 

    SELECT 
    NodeTypeId,
    Name,
    Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Alias

    FROM @TableVariable t
        /*Left Join then where ID is null to make sure the record doesn't exists*/
        LEFT JOIN NWatchNodes PR WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON  PR.ID = @ScalarParameter
                                AND PR.Name = t.Name
        WHERE PR.ID IS NULL
END

GO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662954/query-error-with-ambiguous-column-name-in-sql)

Answer (score 4):

This means you have `NodeTypeId` column in both `@TableVariable` and `NWatchNodes` tables.

In order to resolve it - just use appropriate alias, i.e. `t.NodeTypeId` or `PR.NodeTypeId` in select list.

Answer (score 3):

You have problem in aliases, to further understand the problem, that error means you have the same/similar column name in two tables.

**TIPS:** If you are using aliases on your table, **ALWAYS** specify the alias name of a specific column so that you will not encounter that error.