# SQL query doesnt find exact name from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM hge_funcionarios 
 JOIN hospitais
 ON hge_funcionarios.hospital_id = hospitais.id_hospitais 
 JOIN funcoes
 ON hge_funcionarios.funcao_id = funcoes.id_funcoes
WHERE nome LIKE '%$search%'
ORDER BY hospital_id DESC
```

When I try the exact name from the database doesnt show up any results.
If i search `"Larissa"` or `"LARISSA"`, I get no results even in my database having `"LARISSA CAMPOS"`.

If I try `"lar"` or anything like this I can find it, but when it gets too close to the name on database like `"LARISS"` I can't find it any more.
I tried collate and charset but no success.

EDIT: Its not a Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL because column names are distinct.

Comment: Is there a reason for the $ in the `LIKE` search?

Comment: yes, a variable before receives from $_GET

Comment: @UlissesSilva, you really should never put a variable sourced from user input directly into a query.  Use prepared statements.

Comment: Does `= "LARISSA CAMPOS"` work?  Sounds like it could be a special character in the name.

Comment: no, "LARISSA CAMPOS" doesnt work

Comment: solved "ORDER BY hospital_id DESC" was making this

Comment: specifically "DESC"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662954/query-error-with-ambiguous-column-name-in-sql)

Comment: You should switch on your error/warning/notice warnings whenever things don't go as planned.  Always check your error logs before posting a question SO -- this helps us to quickly and accurately answer your question.  ...but more importantly, you can usually avoid asking a question if you take the time to investigate and research fully before asking for support.

Comment: I dont think its duplicated post i check all and Its not "Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL"

Comment: Use prepared statements and forget about this problem.

Comment: @TheImpaler how do I use that

Comment: Here you go: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Shouldn't "hospitais" be "hospitals"?

Comment: Portuguese @GaryHayes

Comment: @TheImpaler I really dont understand how this can prevent this error, if I need to write the code and I can make some mistakes . Can u explain?

Comment: Try to search for other names and rule out the possibility of the error coming from search character length

Comment: @BobbyAxe If it is  character length what I can do to solve??

Comment: please notice that adding back ticks in stackoverflow highlights the word

Comment: in that case (1) check the database character type length for the `nome` column (2) check if you have overlapping columns on the both tables, that is columns with the same name (3) add back ticks to WHERE `nome` LIKE '%$search%' (4) concatenate your search input like so $search= '%".$search."%' and replace the current one like so WHERE `nome` LIKE $search (5) run your query as it is now but remove the last line remove ORDER BY hospital_id DESC

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer since it's not possible to show it in the comments. Feel free to disregard it.

The problem you are facing seems to be related to the injection of parameter values into your SQL query. The easy (dangerous) way is to simply concatenate strings, as in:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
  "select * from my_table where name = '" . $param1 . "'");
```

Even though it works for simple cases, your case is more complicated, and confusing. Most of the time you'll use **Prepared Statements** as in:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from my_table where name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $param1);
```

This way, the parameter will be injected the right way. In your case you'll need to prepend and append `%` to your parameter, since it'll be used for a `LIKE` operator.

Comment: about sql injection I used it                       $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['search']);

Comment: but is not something big is a private application. I dont see reason for the user sql inject his only information.

Comment: is better I waste my time learing Prepared Statements on MYSQLi or PDO?

Comment: PDO is the newest standard.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE nome LIKE '%$search%'
```

May be $ is the Reason.Try Like :  WHERE nome LIKE **'%search%'**

Comment: That is clearly just a variable that's being added.