# hard to understand how to use self join and it function

Tags: mysql, database, self-join

This is my codding and the value insert to the table.

```
CREATE TABLE provendor (
  prcode varchar (10), 
  prvendor varchar (5),
  prpricing decimal (9,2)
);

INSERT INTO provendor(prcode, prvendor, prpricing)
VALUES  
    ('PW-1001', 'P10', '500.00'),
    ('PQ-4570', 'P88', '35.00'),
    ('MM-120E', 'P67', '245.00'),
    ('MM-F12WR', 'P10', '1210.00'),
    ('PW-QZR-09', 'P10', '79.00'),
    ('PQ-4570', 'P10', '32.50'),
    ('MM-120E', 'P88', '242.00'),
    ('PW-1001', 'P45', '550.00'),
    ('MM-F12WR', 'P73', '1200.00'),
    ('PQ-4570', 'P67', '33.00'),
    ('MM-F12WR', 'P35', '1189.00'),
    ('PW-1001', 'P23', '510.00'),
    ('PQ-4570', 'P35', '36.00'),
    ('MM-120E', 'P23', '250.00');
```

I need to perform a query to retrieve `product code`, the `pricing` and `vendor code` for `product` that supplied by more than one vendors and your record must be sorted by product code.

This is codding that I used for the self join

```
SELECT A.prvendor AS provendor1, B.prvendor AS provendor2, A.prcode
FROM  provendor A, provendor B
WHERE  prvendor1 > A.prcode
ORDER BY A.prcode;
```

When I run it the error will say that `prvendor` values is ambiguous. I dont know how to solve it

Comment: Hi. Read about table aliases in joins in the intro to joins that you should have read before you ran this code. Also google your error message with & without your particular strings next time. You are joining a & b, both have the value of provendor so both have a column prvendor1. Disambiguate by using an alias. This is a faq.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662954/query-error-with-ambiguous-column-name-in-sql)

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: What would be expected output, as per your given sample input table.

Comment: You should read up on sql order of execution. - the where clause executes before the select so cannot see aliases created in the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the table alias in the where clause so you need

```
SELECT A.prvendor AS provendor1, B.prvendor AS provendor2, A.prcode
FROM  provendor A, provendor B
WHERE  A.prvendor > A.prcode
ORDER BY A.prcode;
```

However, you should use the ANSI join syntax as is clearer to understand as is generally seen as best practice:

```
SELECT A.prvendor AS provendor1,
       B.prvendor AS provendor2,
       A.prcode
FROM   provendor A
       JOIN provendor B
           ON A.prvendor > A.prcode
ORDER BY A.prcode;
```