# SQL: preserve original column name from CASE + GROUP BY (+ VIEW) - ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

How to preserve original column name when I use `CASE` to get column from many tables based on condition and I have to use this name in `GROUP BY` because used aggregate function? I need it for create `VIEW` with proper column names. I use PostgreSQL.

#### Example

I have three tables:

```
create table first
(
    id    bigserial primary key,
    field varchar(255) not null
);

create table second
(
    id       bigserial primary key,
    field    varchar(255) not null,
    first_id bigint constraint second_first_id references first
);

create table values
(
    id       bigserial primary key,
    value    numeric,
    first_id bigint constraint value_first_id references first
);
```

Some input data:

```
insert into first (field) values ('aaa');
insert into first (field) values ('bbb');
insert into second (field, first_id) values ('ggg', 1);
insert into second (field, first_id) values ('hhh', 2);
insert into values (value, first_id) values (2, 1);
insert into values (value, first_id) values (4, 1);
insert into values (value, first_id) values (20, 2);
insert into values (value, first_id) values (40, 2);
```

And SQL that join those tables and group by:

```
select sum(v.value) as sum_value,
       f.field,
       s.field
from first f
         left join second s on f.id = s.first_id
         left join values v on f.id = v.first_id
group by f.field, s.field;
```

Now I add `CASE` statement with some condition (`true` for simplicity) to get field `field` from `first` or `second` table:

```
select sum(v.value) as sum_value,
       case
           when true then
               f.field
           else
               s.field
           end      as field
from first f
         left join second s on f.id = s.first_id
         left join values v on f.id = v.first_id
group by field;
```

There is error:

```
ERROR: column reference "field" is ambiguous
```

I could fix the error by change `as field` and `group by field` with new name form example `field1`.

But I want to preserve original name `field`. Its important when I create view:

```
create or replace view my_view as
select sum(v.value) as sum_value,
       case
           when true then
               f.field
           else
               s.field
           end      as field1
from first f
         left join second s on f.id = s.first_id
         left join values v on f.id = v.first_id
group by field1;

select * from my_view;
```

The view returns column with name `field1` instead of `field`.

I try to qualify name `as field` in view by `group by my_view.field` but it also doesn't works:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "my_view"
```

I can copy whole `CASE` statement and paste it in `GROUP BY` but I think it's not a good solution (especially when `CASE` is very long and many columns):

```
create or replace view my_view as
select sum(v.value) as sum_value,
       case
           when false then
               f.field
           else
               s.field
           end      as field
from first f
         left join second s on f.id = s.first_id
         left join values v on f.id = v.first_id
group by case
             when false then
                 f.field
             else
                 s.field
             end;
```

I saw those questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662954/query-error-with-ambiguous-column-name-in-sql), it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe `create or replace view my_view(sum_value, field) as`?

Comment: Thanks @lemon! Using temporary name in select `as field1` and final name `field` in view definition is nice. It solves my specific problem (because I use view), but I have to copy all names to view definition. And also I was hoping to find more generic solution (without view, only select) - some way to qualify the name or double naming with `as`, but I don't know it is possible.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. And you're using a case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: You can use a sub-select or CTE to run aggregation on outer query.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the ordinal of the column in the group by. ie:

```
select sum(v.value) as sum_value,
       case
           when true then
               f.field
           else
               s.field
           end      as field
from first f
         left join second s on f.id = s.first_id
         left join values v on f.id = v.first_id
group by 2;
```